# How set Searchbar for Collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I am developing one iPad application using storyboard.In My storyboard I have two collection views with names `nameCollectionView` and `dataColletionView` and one table view with name `languageTableView`. I need to implement search bar for `nameCollectionView`. For this `CollectionView` I configure cell using data from `resultArray`.

My first questions are: 
1) Is it possible to set search bar for collection view?
2) How can I set search bar for my name collection view?

Some one help me to implement the following features.

Comment: The main idea is that, you don't set the searchBar for the collectionView; you set the searchBar for the data from the resultArray, after that you instantiate a newCollectionView with the data from the searchResult and add it on the top of the initialCollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you should try it like this:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *) searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
if (searchBar.text && [searchBar.text length]) {
    NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text];
    self.filteredData= [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];

} else {
    self.filteredData = allData;
}

[nameCollectionView reloadData];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**CollectionView + SearchBar** with **Swift3 + Storyboard** implementation.

**Creating the Header View:**

[image: Creating the Header View]

**Creating the Search Bar:**

[image: Creating the Search Bar]

**Create the reusable view custom class**

[image: Create the reusable view custom class]

**Set the reusable view custom class**

[image: Set the reusable view custom class]

**Create the search bar outlet**

[image: Create the search bar outlet in custom class]

**Trick: Connect the search bar delegate to COLLECTION VIEW class, the search bar outlet goes to the CUSTOM REUSABLE VIEW CLASS**

[image: Connect the search bar delegate to collection view class]

**Implement the CollectionView header method of protocol**

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

         if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
             let headerView:UICollectionReusableView =  collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewHeader", for: indexPath)

             return headerView
         }

         return UICollectionReusableView()

    }
```

**Set the Searchbar delegate**

```
    class MyCollectionViewController: (other delegates...), UISearchBarDelegate {
```

**And finally, your the search bar delegate methods will be called in your CollectionView Class**

```
//MARK: - SEARCH

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if(!(searchBar.text?.isEmpty)!){
        //reload your data source if necessary
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if(searchText.isEmpty){
        //reload your data source if necessary
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes is possible. 2. Here it is:

==================================

```
#pragma mark - Search Bar Delegate
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = true; }

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    //Remove first
    [self.filteredNames removeAllObjects];
    [self.filteredSections removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        isSearching = true;
        // Filter the array using NSPredicate

        for (int i = 0; i<[self.allNames count]; i++) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
            NSArray *predicatedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.allNames[i] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

            if([predicatedArray count] != 0){
                [self.filteredNames addObject:predicatedArray];
                [self.filteredSections addObject:[self.orderedSections objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        isSearching = false;
        self.filteredNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.allNames];
        self.filteredSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.orderedSections];
    }
    [self.collectionView reloadData]; }

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { }

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; }






#pragma mark - Collection Delegate Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return [self.filteredNames count]; }

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[self.filteredNames objectAtIndex:section] count]; }

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;


    //Header
    //if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
    NamesListCollectionHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"NamesListCollectionHeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (headerView==nil) {
        headerView  = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NamesListCollectionHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if (self.filteredSections.count != 0) {
        //Text
        headerView.title.text=[self.filteredSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }else{
        headerView.title.text=@"";
    }

    reusableview = headerView;
    return reusableview;

    //Footer
    //if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {}

    return nil;
     }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Init of the Cell
    NameCollectionCellController *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NameCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[NameCollectionCellController alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 140.0f, 160.0f)];
    }

    //Name
    Name *curName;

    curName = [[self.filteredNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Set Cell
    [cell setCell];

    //Set Selected
    if (curName == ((NamesViewController*)self.parentViewController).curName) {
        [cell setSelected:YES];
        [cell setSelectedBorder];
    }else{
        [cell setDeselected];
        [cell setSelected:NO];
    }

    //Title
    cell.nameValueLabel.text = curName.name;

    return cell; }

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self collectionView:self.collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:self.curIndexPath];

    //Set Cur Name
    if ([self. filteredNames count]>0) {

        self.curIndexPath = indexPath;
        ((NamesViewController*)self.parentViewController).curName
= [[self.filteredNAmes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        self.curCell = (NameCollectionCellController *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.curCell setSelectedBorder];
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didSelectNameNotification" object:self];
    } }

-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath!=nil) {
        [self.curCell setDeselected];
    } }
```